# Is nested interpolation possible with git for-each-ref

Tags: git

When specifying the `--format` parameter for [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), can I use an interpolated value as a parameter to another interpolated value?  Specifically, I'd like to see the ahead-behind counts for branches on different remotes, so I'd like to interpolate the branch name into `%(ahead-behind)` as `%(ahead-behind:origin/%(refname:strip=3))`.

I'm able to use `%(ahead-behind)` without nested interpolation by using a fixed reference, like `HEAD`:

```bash
$ git for-each-ref \
    --format='%(refname:strip=3) %(ahead-behind:HEAD)' \
    refs/remotes/oldlaptop
```

But, I get an error when I try to nest the interpolation in order to reference a branch with the same name on a different remote:

```bash
$ git for-each-ref \
    --format='%(refname:strip=3) %(ahead-behind:origin/%(refname:strip=3))' \
    refs/remotes/oldlaptop
fatal: failed to find 'origin/%(refname:strip=3'
```

Is there some other syntax that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the option was coded with a "compare all refs to a fixed reference" in mind.

One use case is: for each branch, have a view of how many commits ahead/behind you would have if you opened a merge request
see for example this post:
https://github.blog/2023-06-01-highlights-from-git-2-41/  (search for the "If you’ve looked at a repository’s branches page on GitHub ..." paragraph)

The code (see `ref-filter.c`<sup>1</sup> [l.957](https://github.com/git/git/blob/98d0a1f93e869b29041de9122fe31a62c40a4e78/ref-filter.c#L957) and [l.888](https://github.com/git/git/blob/98d0a1f93e869b29041de9122fe31a62c40a4e78/ref-filter.c#L888)) also shows that the `:committish` reference is turned into a commit hash *once* as soon as the format string is parsed -- as opposed to: re-interpreted on each iteration.

---

The workaround is to loop over the output lines and execute a new command to have the ahead/behind count.

Here is an example:

```
$ git for-each-ref \
    --format='%(refname:strip=3) origin/%(refname:strip=3)' \
    refs/remotes/oldlaptop |
   while read branch upstream; do
     git for-each-ref \
       --format="$branch [ahead %(ahead-behind:$upstream) behind] $upstream" \
       oldlaptop/"$branch";
   done

# sample output:
master [ahead 12 16 behind] origin/master
...
```

---

@jthill suggested the following variant: have `git for-each-ref` print the command to run for each ref:

```
git for-each-ref \
  --format="git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:strip=3) %%(ahead-behind=origin/%(refname:strip=3))' %(refname)" \
  refs/remotes/oldlaptop

# check that the above command generates an output that makes sense,
# then run:
<command...> | bash
```

---

<sup>1</sup> state of `master` branch on 2023-12-14

Comment: I'd just use the first f-e-r to generate the desired f-e-r commands, run them as a second pass, fingers-to-textbox `--format="git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:strip=3) %%(ahead-behind=origin/%(refname:strip=3))' refs/remotes/laptop" | sh`

Comment: @jthill: nice idea :)